# How to dectect open a file in java

Tags: java

I want to write an java application. It runs in background and when user trys to open a file or a directory (double click or right click and choose open) in a certain folder, an event will be generated and I can do something in the event handler. Is it possible to detect this in java? Btw, it seems java.nio package cannot detect this..

Comment: This only picks up file and directory changes.

Comment: I will remove the comment now

Comment: Have in mind that double-click only executes an OS action over the file (some defined command). Depending on file extension and configuration OS will execute a command using file name as parameter. Nothing more. Or what you are trying to do is more related with the concrete OS file browser, or it's more related with some other particularity (like locked files, by example)

Comment: So it is not likely to detect double click in java, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can poll all the files to see if they have been locked on windows.

There is no way to tell if a file is opened by the directly user or simply scanned by another program e.g. word search.

I suspect whatever you are trying to do is done better or more reliably another way.

Comment: +1 for 'I suspect whatever you are trying to do is dome better or more reliably another way'

Comment: Although he might want to catch whenever **any** file is opened. It is not really possible to watch all files in a modern computer setup without having a huge detection delay (lots and lots of files...)

Comment: Actually I no not want to know if the file is opened. I just want to get the open event. My case is like, e.g. there is an empty file, when user double click it, an event will be generated and in the event handler, the program will download the file content from a sever and open it for user.

Comment: I suspect what you are trying to do isn't supported by the operating system.  The closest you can do to this is to create a custom file system driver (e.g. drop box's drive letter) This is very low level (not something you can do in Java) but would give you this "event"

Answer (score 0):

watch for directory changes. Have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)

Comment: There are no events for a file being opened there.

Comment: I did. Can you please explain how that would help achieve what OP wants?

Comment: When user open a file, nothing has been changed, I think.